# How to Convert Long time to UTC and return it in long

Tags: java, jodatime

I have this method which i get a local time in Long and i want to change it to UTC and return the results in Long
I do the following, it seems like that the changing to UTC doesn't seems to be working .

```
private Long convertToUtc(Long localTime){

  DateTime dt = new DateTime(localTime);
  dt.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
  return  dt.getMillis();
 }
```

Comment: which format you want the out put, is it in millis?

Comment: @itsmeisuru - yes i return it in milis. will be format in the UI

Comment: From where are you getting the Long time? Java uses time since the epoc in utc which means that it will allways be the same no matter timezone you are in. The timezone is put on in the handling of the output of that date.

Comment: @Nir This is a feature not a bug. `DateTime` and nearly all classes in Joda-Time are immutable. You cannot change any members in a DateTime instance. You can only create *new* DateTime instances perhaps based on other instances but with a difference such as switching time zones. Notice in Rohit Jain's answer's example code that a second DateTime object (`dtWithZone`) is being instantiated. In contrast, your code was trying and failing to alter the first instance. Actually, your line with `.UTC` is generating a new instance but then failing to capture it. *Poof* – gone into the digital ether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime#withZone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) method (Note: It returns a new `DateTime` object. So you need to re-assign it back to a new `DateTime` reference)

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(localTime);
DateTime dtWithZone = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
return dtWithZone.getMillis();
```